Inbox not marked as read
When someone posts a comment on a question or answer from me, I get a notification in my inbox.
If I click the notification and get redirected to the question, that notification itself is not marked as read.
I have to use the link mark all as read every time to get that number from anything to 0.

The above screenshot is AFTER I clicked on the bottom link to get here.

Do you have adblock? I have the same problem and I suspect its my adblock, but I have multiple levels of adblock and I'm not sure which it is.

This was paired with another issue but see the comments https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/401151/flagging-deleted-post-or-clicking-on-inbox-item-fails-and-brings-up-an-error-500

FYI... I also have this issue, sometimes it works and other times it does not. I do not use any adblocker and use Chrome for SuperUser web browser. Sometimes it seems to work, then when you go back later, it is like the same message (or messages) state you have not read them yet. I have observed this too.

@JourneymanGeek I disabled my adblockers (uBlock origin, and Vivaldi's build-in, refreshed the page, clicked the comment for this page, and nope... still unread.

Hm. I run Vivaldi too . I will see if I can document it further on my end and possibly status review it. It's not a supported browser, so I want to maximize my chances of getting it fixed

Vivaldi is basically Chrome, but modified. But thanks for your efforts @JourneymanGeek

Here is an example after I clicked on it, left a comment, then it still flagged as red: https://imgur.com/yoG0XT6—I see it from Chrome from time-to-time like this.

Happens in Firefox running uBlock Origin as well.

The notifications, after I click them, are not even marked as read on my end. I go to the link it provides, but they're not marked as read either, and nor does the number changed. The link Read All is the only one that works, and this is across all the computers I use.

@JourneymanGeek just curious, have you been able to get more into this? This problem still happens on my end.

I am half certain it's AdBlock related , but never really narrowed it down unfortunately.

@JourneymanGeek I'll pause my adblock on superuser in all ways possible on my terminal server and see if the problem goes away. I am using Vivaldi though, so the problem may be in that too.

That's part of the problem for me - I have ublock, vivaldi's own blocking and a network wide adblocker, and I'm not annoyed enough yet to troubleshoot all of them

@JourneymanGeek well, I've disabled my adblocker for both meta.superuser.com and inside vivaldi, and this notification still doesn't work. I'll disable the extension entirely and try that. I am using stylus too for CSS editing, maybe that somehow interferes.

@JourneymanGeek I had disabled adblocker entirely, but vivaldi syncs that to my other pc, where I use youtube, so that just was not an option. Its enabled again, but haven't had a notification in the meanwhile, so I'm not sure.... But not gonna test it as this annoyance is not as bad as ads all over the place on my main pc.
